# Why does this works as string when it should only work as number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, primes

So I was putting this code from an exercise on node.js in a format to front-end javascript so I could upload like a webpage. It checks if the number is prime or not. The code is:

```
let num = 6
let divisions = 0

for (let n = 1; n <= num; n++) { 
    if (num % n == 0) { 
        divisions++
    }
}
if (divisions == 2) {
    console.log(`O número ${num} é primo!`)
} else {
    console.log(`O número ${num} não é primo!`) 
}
```

This works just fine on the console.

As for the HTML5 page, I put the code inside an onclick function and just altered the variable so it gets a number from an number input box. And changed the last part to change the `innerHTML` of the result div instead of a `console.log`. And a simple alert to check if the number is higher than 2.

```
    function verifyPrime() {
      let num = document.getElementById('txtnum')
if (num <= 1 || num.length == 0){
    alert('insert numbers 2 or higher')
```

But then things went wrong. The template literals returned an `[object HTMLInputElement]`error. A `console.log(typeof(num)` returned object on the console, which I didn't get it.

Then I added a `.value` at the end of the getElement command. It then returned the correct number, but the typeof said it was a string.

Lastly, I added a `Number()` to the whole, which returned the number and the correct typeof.

My questions are:

1- Why the simple first command returned an useless object for the script?

2- Why does the script works normally when it gets a string? Shouldn't it work just with numbers since booth the loop and the second if/else asks for numbers?

I know that if it's working, it's fine... but I want to have a deeper undestanding of coding logic! Thank you!

Comment: 1) You were returning the element, not the value/html/text content. Values/html/text content from DOM elements will always be strings unless you coerce them to be something else. 2) Look up [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality): `==` is not the same as =`===`. The latter checks both type and value, the former just the value (probably with some type coercion going on).

Comment: For 1 - this time it didn't returned a string, but an object. Confirmed by typeof. I had to add the .value so it returned a string. That's what got me wondering.